# Background multithreading (unresponsive UI)

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, backgroundworker, freeze

Essentially I've been using multithreading and it hasn't been working the way it should be. I immediately tried to describe the issue in a title to find an answer online but found nothing in relation.

Here's an application I developed to better understand multitasking so I can effectively use in actual applications.

[image]

So essentially what it does is you write something in the textbox and choose how many threads you want and it will append the log box on the bottom. So it will show how many times each thread has run *BUT* the issue is that it still makes the UI freeze whilst in the background.

Here's the output it gives on 3 threads (it can handle a low amount of (less than 10) threads):

[image]

Here is the complete code -

```
public partial class thread : Form
{
    Thread[] threads;
    int amountOf;
    bool stop = false;
    int threadAmt = 0;

    public thread()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        amountOf = (int)amtThreads.Value;
        threads = new Thread[amountOf];
        //Define threads
        for (int i = 0; i < amountOf; i++)
        {
            threads[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(job));
        }
       //Start threads
       foreach (Thread t in threads)
       {
           t.IsBackground = true;
           t.Start();
       }
    }

    private void logIt(string text)
    {
        if (outputResult.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback cb = new SetTextCallback(logIt);
            Invoke(cb, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
            outputResult.AppendText(text);
    }

    private void job()
    {
        int threadNum = threadAmt++;
        int howMany = 0;
        do
        {
            howMany++;
            logIt("Thread: " + threadNum + " : Processed " + howMany + " times : Saying " + writeText.Text + Environment.NewLine);
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
        while (!stop);
    }

    private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        Start.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + e.Error.Message);
        else if (e.Cancelled)
            MessageBox.Show("Application canceled.");
    }

    private void Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        stop = true;
        backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
        Stop.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void Clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        outputResult.Clear();
    }
}
```

The UI continues to freeze after putting 10 or more threads.
Another thing I wanted to know is pausing and resuming the threads. When you stop the threads loop then re-enable it it'll only show a single result. It wont continue the loop.

Comment: I don't see a reason for spawning other threads when you are already in an background thread if the goal is simply to keep the UI responsive.

Comment: @UweKeim Like it's been indicated in the application that this is a test to further improve upon multithreading before I implement it into actual applications. If something this basic can't handle multithreading with the way I've implemented it then how will that application act? This is the first time I used multithreading in this context and for a first time it went okay but I'm looking for improvements and answers to code more effectively too.

Comment: I suspect when you dramatically increase the number of threads running simultaneously (why you would be running more than the number of cores available is beyond me...) you're simply crushing the UI thread with InvokeRequired checks (they're always required from a background thread), and subsequent Invoke commands. Try increasing the `Thread.Sleep` value.

Comment: I would _always_ prefer [`ThreadPool`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool) over creating my own threads.

Comment: @Lathejockey81 I'm pretty sure an average computer would be able to handle more threads than the cores in the system without making the UI be unresponsive. It may just be excessive threads; do you see any problem in my code that could influence the UI freezing? First time really using multithreading practically with no references. I usually use Thread.Sleep(1) to free up memory consumption as it's essentially undetectable in the UI. Would you distribute them a little more or increase the single one?

Comment: @UweKeim What benefits does ThreadPool provide over multiple threads running at once? The key thing I wanted was to have multiple instances of the same code running at exactly the same time. So while one performs a check so does the other getting results at slightly different intervals.

Comment: Personally, I do believe that I do _not_ have the deep knowledge to manage the threads correctly so I use the high-level implementation of the `ThreadPool` class that I get for free. In fact, I have lots of fear to suffer from the [Dunning-Kruger effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect) whenever I develop code (no joke!)

Comment: @UweKeim See that's what a great coding community like stackoverflow is for. Coders getting together with all different skill bases & ranges to help with incorrect or improper coding techniques. I hope to improve from any mistakes I have and have them pointed out to me no matter how directly it's done. Only then can you overcome the fear of not believing your ability is as good as it is or vice versa. The issue with ThreadPool is that it's asynchronous and may not work as fast as multithreading will. I'm looking for speed and consecutive instances of the same code repeating with no drawbacks.

Comment: @Nick _"The issue with ThreadPool is that it's asynchronous and may not work as fast as multithreading will"_ - ThreadPool is not purely for async [I/O].  I think what you mean is that because of it's queued design, some workitems may not run right away depending upon load.  MSDN: _[Queues a method for execution. The method executes when a thread pool thread becomes available](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem(v=vs.110).aspx)_.  The newer `Task` class is rather nice compared to explicitly creating threads or using workitems via `ThreadPool`

Comment: @MickyDuncan Okay so essentially you could set a maximum of say 3 threads to occur and ThreadPool will have 3 running at the same time. When one completed the next thread in queue will start; this loop will continue until told to stop. If that correct? If so is there a way to pause those threads and resume them?

Comment: @Nick - I think that is a very interesting scenario and probably worth a whole new SO question. :)  Theoretically yes however,  on a quad-core computer you can't set it to 3 (less than number of cores).  Apparently IIS may ignore any changes you make too. _[Tell more more...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads(v=vs.110).aspx)_.  Also I'm pretty sure I read somewhere here on SO that changes to thread pool limits gets complex depending upon OS; number of apps running and so on.

Comment: @MickyDuncan I'll definitely look into thread pools and do some tests with them. If anything comes up I'll definitely post a new SO question. It is a different process and a whole new question compared to the one we're discussing. The question I asked you on your answer also poses another scenario for multithreading which requires pausing. :)

Comment: @Nick You might also want to check out _TPL Dataflow_ in .NET.  It allows for some nice fine control of levels of concurrency; max messages per block.

Comment: @Nick No worries Nick.  Good luck!

Comment: @MickyDuncan Thank you, I appreciate that. I'll also look into TPL Dataflow, it seems worthwhile. I marked your response as the answer; cheers for all the help!

Comment: @Nick I never claimed one would crush the CPU by running more threads than cores, that would make any OS unusable. In the contrived situation where each thread is doing actual work rather than just waiting for something one would not *gain* anything from throwing more threads than available cores at the problem, so it seems wasteful to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not so much *creating excessive threads* rather **your threads are excessively updating the UI**.

Your `job` method has a very tight loop where you call `logIt` then sleep for **one millisecond then repeat the process.**  The log marshals the call to the UI thread where `outputResult.AppendText(text);` is called.  This marshalling happens over the message pump.

You're essentially overflowing the message pump with essentially updates to the `TextBox` and so the UI becomes unresponsive being unable to process anything else.

Multiply that out by 10 threads all logging with miniscule waits between logging and your UI will freeze.

Consider increasing the `Thread.Sleep` to say `Thread.Sleep(500)` for 1/2 second.

Change this code:

```
private void job()
{
    int threadNum = threadAmt++;
    int howMany = 0;
    do
    {
        howMany++;
        logIt("Thread: " + threadNum + " : Processed " + howMany + " times : Saying " + writeText.Text + Environment.NewLine);
        Thread.Sleep(1); // Oww!!  Should this have been 1000 instead of 1.   1000 is 1 second.
    }
    while (!stop);
}
```

...to:

```
private void job()
{
    int threadNum = threadAmt++;
    int howMany = 0;
    do
    {
        howMany++;
        logIt("Thread: " + threadNum + " : Processed " + howMany + " times : Saying " + writeText.Text + Environment.NewLine);
        Thread.Sleep(500); // e.g. 1/2 second 
    }
    while (!stop);
}
```

### Alternative Design

It's great you are interested in threading.  .NET has made threading much easier since `Thread` was introduced, particularly when threads need to manipulate the UI.  Now days it is usually better not to explicitly create threads but to use the alternative APIs.

You might want to look .NET *asynchronous methods* via the `async` and the `await` keywords as they might be quite useful in your case.

A topic for another time

Comment: Yes I definitely could see that being an issue - 1 millisecond had no direct effect on the form and simply was there to free up excess consumption of the CPU. With the Thread.Sleep(500) being half a second that would also stop every other thread as well wouldn't it? Or would it just stop that singular thread executing for half a second? One last thing I also wanted to know is with the backgroundworker - if I add else MessageBox.Show("Backgroundworker Finished"); to the RunWorkerCompleted it will instantly output this as the background task starts. That isn't an indication of anything is it?

Comment: @Nick No, `Thread.Sleep` suspends the _current_ thread only.  Re `Backgroundworker Finished` - no, it just means that your `BackgroundWorker` has completed.  It's job was to spawn those other threads you are creating. Even though the worker has completed, it does not imply your other threads have.

Comment: I appreciate that cheers. I always thought that Thread was a direct impact on the UI simply because I usually only use a single thread; the application. And I never though in too much detail in relation to the BackgroundWorker's events. There's one thing I want to know since it's the threads that are overloading the UI causing it to freeze. With pausing multithreading and restarting it how would you go about it? It seems simply changing stop = true then overwriting the threads again only makes them run a single time. I tried foreach Thread x.Suspend() but it's depreciated?

Comment: You could 'suspend' the threads in varying ways but a better approach perhaps is that you want to gather your 'updates' into one or more batches that can then be processed by the UI at a more leisurely pace.  e.g. instead of writing to the UI have all the threads write to a shared [ConcurrentBag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx) that the main UI thread during say [Application.Idle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.idle(v=vs.110).aspx) could process.  There are many other ways.  This way threads can just focus on compute

Comment: Wouldn't that still consume resources and essentially still have the threads running but at a concise pace? The thread instances would still be running consuming CPU resources. The suspend method should essentially pauses the threads until they're told to resume. However it didn't do this and the direct suspend method is depreciated. For example say there's a case where one application has two methods and two types of multithreading. One needs to pause and the other needs to keep going to we don't want them to continue until resumed otherwise it may freeze the UI or consume resources.

Comment: Yes, but the UI won't be frozen anymore.  We don't want to suspend and resume threads all the time because we created them to do something in the first place, particularly to do so just so as to avoid freezing the UI.   Generally you want to avoid updating the UI from a worker thread.  It's expensive.  Also note, when the worker thread calls `Invoke` it will block that worker thread until the UI has carried out the `outputResult.AppendText(text)`, which in your case will be some time.

Comment: Okay but say in a scenario the thread is making a web request and also consuming your servers resources so you need to pause the thread completely. Is it possible to resume it after being paused or will the application need to be restarted? Right now for this application I agree with you that it won't matter if we move it to say another collection. We could instantly fix the UI issue with a Thread.Sleep(500); so say that wasn't the issue and the server consumption was an issue. Just trying to assume all scenarios since this current application was only a test for me to learn as much as I can.

Comment: @Nick It sounds like you are concerned that during this time it is eating up resources that you would like to give to other active threads? That's a good thought and for that we have I/O Completion Ports (IOCP) & here it benefits what is essentially waiting on a network operation to complete. What you should do here is call the asynchronous version of the web request like `await client.DoWebRequestAsync(...).ConfigureAwait(false)`.  The request is made & in the mean time the **current thread will automatically go off and do something else** so to speak until the response comes back.

Comment: The nice thing about `await client.DoWebRequestAsync(...)` is that the request can be made from your UI thread and it won't block nor waste threads!